# Data Format/Schema for Command in CQRS Application

Tags: cqrs

I've been experimenting with the CQRS pattern recently, and in a lot of documentation it appears that people send commands externally from the application to the command handlers using a queue.

One thing I am interested in, is what format do people send the commands in? I can see that JSON would be a good representation format, however how do you manage versioning of the incoming commands?

I assume that there is something that needs to read from the command queue, deserialize the parameters for the command and then execute them via the CommandHandler implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question. There a few things to think about when thinking of versioning. I like to follow a set of principles:

1. Never rename a field
2. Never delete a field

However, you may just need to retire or a completely different form. In which case I like to use a post fix. e.g. _V2

Key thing to bear in mind is to keep the content of the command to simple types. There may be exceptional circumstances when you want complex types but I would try to avoid this.

Changing commands is less of an issue in the long run (unless you record your commands) than changing/versioning events.

In case it's helpful I have a blog post on versioning events without busting your event stream. You can find it: [here](http://danielwhittaker.me/2015/02/02/upgrade-cqrs-events-without-busting/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When you're doing CQRS do you use a queue for sending the commands through?